Google Maps Directions API: Is it Possible to Specify Multiple Departure Times in One Request for Hourly Traffic Data?
I want to display a chart showcasing the hourly traffic for a specific route on Google Maps. Based on the documentation, it seems I need to call the API multiple times to retrieve traffic data for different hourly intervals. Is there an API that allows me to pass multiple departure times in a single request and retrieve all the corresponding traffic data?
Thankyou!

Could you please raise a feature request in Google Public Issue Tracker?
